# Как мне запустить из программы x-сервер(cygwin)?

Tags: c, cygwin

Я написал программу gtk, работает она в среде cygwin.

Чтобы запустить программу(точнее чтобы gtk работал) я должен запустить x-сервер,  запускаться программа должна по двойному клику на exe файл, соответственно запускать через какой-нибудь xlaunch не вариант.

Вот что написал в программе для запуска x-сервера:

```
system("startxwin >/dev/null 2>&1 &");//запускаем x-сервер
setenv ("DISPLAY", ":0", 0);//export DISPLAY=:0
```

Это работает, но только если я запускаю программу от имени администратора, иначе команда `startxwin >/dev/null 2>&1 &` не работает. При это все работает, делая тоже самое в терминале cygwin, а я не хочу запускать прогу через терминал.

Как мне запустить из программы этот ****** x-сервер без прав администратора?

Вопрос все еще в ожидании ответа

Comment: Возможно я пишу глупость, но почему бы не запускать программу gtk в среде windows без всяких там cygwin?

Comment: @andreymal, я пробовал перенести программу на windows, это оказалось очень трудно, одного кода 10к строк. Если компилировать MinGW, то придется очень много чего переписывать. Времени, сил, да и желания на это нет